# Angular mediumTime Date pipe displays formatted time for "00:00:00" as "12:09:24 AM"

Tags: angular

The app is reading from a web service (not under my control) that returns a date variable as "0001-01-01T00:00:00" which is supposed to mean "midnight".  However, when I ask angular to format the date as a mediumTime I get "12:09:24 AM".  I don't understand where the 9 minutes and 24 seconds is coming from.

Plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hdC4cFYkSdw2E8RzhFJP?p=preview

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Object:</h2>
<pre>{{myThing | json}}</pre>
      <h2>Message Time: {{myThing.messageTime}}</h2>
      <h2>The message time formatted is {{myThing.messageTime | date:'mediumTime'}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

**Typescript**

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  myThing: MyThing;

  constructor() {
    var json = '{ "messageTime" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00", "message" : "This is your message"}';
    this.myThing = <MyThing>JSON.parse(json);
  }
}

export class MyThing
{
  messageTime: date;
  message: string;
}
```

Comment: Plunker displays `The message time formatted is 12:00:04 AM`

Comment: This isn't the first time I've have weird behavior with the date pipe.  For me Chrome and Firefox say "12:09:24 AM"  and IE says "12:00:00 AM".  Something about the original date string maybe - need more information?

Comment: Personally I always use epoch with DatePipe, since that is an unambiguous time scale. Note that if you swap `0001-01-01T00:00:00` to `0001-01-01GMT00:00:00` it will display the correct time based on your system clock.  Errors may also be coming from the fact that DatePipe uses your browser's view of your system's time.